# Javascript : remove array index based on value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which has unique values. I want to remove array index based on its value.

I want to splice the  `arr` when it finds the correct eventName.

any help would be great.

Thank You.

```
arr = [{label : 'Event 1' , value : 'EVENT_1'}, {label : 'Event 2' , value : 'EVENT_2'} , {label : 'Event 3' , value : 'EVENT_3'}]

console.log("Arr Values : " , arr )

removeData = (eventName)   => {
   for(let i = 0 ; i< arr.length; i++) {             
         if(eventName === arr[i].value){

         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that?

```js
const arr = [{label : 'Event 1' , value : 'EVENT_1'}, {label : 'Event 2' , value : 'EVENT_2'} , {label : 'Event 3' , value : 'EVENT_3'}];

const res = arr.filter(obj => obj.value !== 'EVENT_1');

console.log(res);
```